# Can I use a 11-23 11-speed Shimano cassette with the RD-R8000 11-speed Ultegra Shadow rear derailleur (short cage)?

Tags: shimano

I would like to know whether I can use a 11-23 11-speed shimano cassette with the RD-R8000 11-speed Ultegra Shadow Rear Derailleur (short cage).

I ask this question because I see the new 11-speed Shimano cassettes no longer come in a 11-23 gearing.

Looking forward to your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not according to Shimano, anyway. The Shimano specs pages are [here](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec), and [this](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/ROAD/Rear%20Derailleur) is the road rear derailleur page.

The *specified* RD-R8000-SS minimum low sprocket size is 25 teeth.

Comment: FWIW, my [2018 Fuji Transonic 2.3](https://archive.fujibikes.com/2018/Fuji/transonic-234), with an RD-R8000 works just fine with an 11-23.  Makes for a nice trainer cassette, too.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you'll be just fine, although it's technically outside the spec'd range.

Per the [**Shimano 2019-2020 Products compatibility Information**](https://productinfo.shimano.com/download/pdf/com/2.4/en) document (warning: PDF link), the RD-R8000 rear derailleur is compatible with all of the following cassettes:

```
CS-R9100
CS-9000
CS-6800
CS-5800
CS-R8000
CS-HG800-11
CS-R7000
CS-HG700-11
```

As far as I know, that covers all of Shimano's 11-speed road cassettes, and I'm assuming Shimano doesn't produce an 11-23 MTB cassette.

**BUT**

The RD-R8000 is spec'd as

```
    RD-R8000-SS
(25T≤CS Low gear≤30T)
```

(the GS is similary spec'd with a 28T minimum)

so a 23-tooth sprocket would be slightly too small per Shimano's specs.

But it should work for you as Shimano's spec's are notoriously tight - and I already do have an 11-23 on a bike with an RD-8000-SS and it works fine with an 11-23. (I didn't even know it wasn't "in spec"...)

The page the info was extracted from:

[image]

Comment: 28T minimum? Are you sure? The minimum is usually 11T for Shimano RD but for short cage, MAXimum is 28T, for middle cage (they existed)  it was 32T and for long cage it is 34T Road derailleurs. In the 11-28 cassette there's a 23 so why should 11-23 not be compatible?

Comment: @Carel On page 17 of the PDF linked, both the RD-R9100-SS and RD-R8000-SS are spec'd as "(25T≤CS Low gear≤30T)", while the RD-9000, RD-R8000-GS, and RD-RX800-GS are spec'd as "(28T≤CS Low gear≤34T)"  So for SS short cage, the latest 11-speed rear derailleurs are not spec'd to work with any cassette with a large sprocket smaller than 25t, and the long-cage GS derailleurs are not spec'd to work with a cassette that has a large sprocket smaller than 28t.  Will they work in reality?  Probably, and probably quite well.  But the specs are clear.

Comment: @Carel (cont)  The [RD-8000-SS page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/product/component/ultegra-r8000/RD-R8000-SS.html) has both "Low sprocket_Max.  30T" and "Low sprocket_Min.  25T".  Seems crazy, but that's what Shimano says.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thanks for your answer!!! very, VERY enlightening!

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks.  I did find this strange.  It's pure speculation on my part, but what I guess is going on is that Shimano is having trouble getting their electronic DI2 shifting to work well with derailleurs that can handle 11-23 all the way to 11-34 cassettes, and there's no way Shimano will say that the "low end" systems such as manual-shifting 105 can work with cassettes all the from 11-23 to 11-34 when the top-end "premium" electronic-shifting DuraAce DI2 can't be made to shift well with such a large range.  Because the 11-23 works fine for me, and I can't see pros giving 11-23s up.

Comment: Shimano says many strange things in their data sheets. I've been running for two years and over 10.000km  with UltegraDi2 with a 52-34 front without trouble (you shouldn't according to S.) and various rear cassettes 11-25, 11-28, 11-32. I'd try an 11-23 if I had one. Chainlife >3000km. I'd say their datasheets are ultra-cautious.